# How to Split Fetched rows from SQL database into batches

Tags: python

Using python how to Split SQL query result into batches like .

My MSSQL query return 1000 rows and I want to split 1000 rows into 10 batches and sent to other function

Comment: Read about "limit" clause in SQL.

Comment: I want this in MSSQL and using python for loop to split into batches